# How to make a simple Timeline UI?

Tags: android, flutter, timeline

I am going to make a timeline interface that shows us the progress going. In this case for the marketplace.

Here what I want:

[image]

I was looking for the code but I can't find the way to make it.

I mean I'm not going to using stack with this case

Comment: no. its not stepper what I want. because stepper contain number inside the circle,
its like steps how to do something.

Comment: Now you can use timeline_tile, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/timeline_list)

```
import 'package:timeline_list/timeline.dart';
import 'package:timeline_list/timeline_model.dart';

List<TimelineModel> items = [
      TimelineModel(Placeholder(),
          position: TimelineItemPosition.random,
          iconBackground: Colors.redAccent,
          icon: Icon(Icons.blur_circular)),
      TimelineModel(Placeholder(),
          position: TimelineItemPosition.random,
          iconBackground: Colors.redAccent,
          icon: Icon(Icons.blur_circular)),
    ];
    return Timeline(children: items, position: TimelinePosition.Center);
```

[image]

Comment: yes I've see that library.
but it's look like to complicated.
because I'm going to make different timeline in the different interface.

Comment: it also has a problem for multi lingual apps, this does not change the widgets

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do this easily with [timeline_tile](https://github.com/JHBitencourt/timeline_tile).

Check out this specific delivery layout:

[image]

Also, the [beautiful_timelines](https://github.com/JHBitencourt/beautiful_timelines) repository contains some examples built with this package.

[Web demo](https://jhbitencourt.github.io/beautiful-timelines/#/)